# How to copy a URL in Linux using Lynx?

Tags: linux, lynx

I would like to know how to copy the current link "highlighted" in Lynx.

I know that if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> it shows you the URL but I don't know how to copy it to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to show the address of the current document, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to show the address of the selected link and then you can copy the text with your mouse.

If it is a SSH access then you can use normal mouse selection to copy and paste the link.

Answer (score 1):

the current lynx help files include Reference for [Keystroke Commands](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/keystrokes/keystroke_help.html), and includes:

> `a` Add the current link to a bookmark file
>
> `d` Download the current link
>
> `l` List references (links) in current document
>
> `.` Run external program on the current link

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the link (or just select it). Once you do that the link will appear on the bottom of the screen. You can select and copy that address. If you want the current page URL it is the same as in Lynx, which is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.